# BigCartel - Removing sidebar on Entry Page in 'Sidecar' theme

Tags: themes, bigcartel

So I'm trying to make an entry page in the BigCartel theme 'Sidecar'. I have managed to get an image in there fine that is clickable to be redirected to my products however I want to be able to remove the side navigation links/icons on the entry page - so it's purely just the image being shown & once the customer clicks on the image to be taken to the shop the side bar appears - is this doable?

I appreciate all thoughts & comments - thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

There might be more elegant methods, but this seems to work.

(1) In **'Layout'**, find `<aside>` and add `{% if page.name != 'Home' %}` before it, like:

```
{% if page.name != 'Home' %}
<aside>
```

Then find `</aside>` and add `{% endif %}` after it:

```
</aside>
{% endif %}
```

The sidebar is `<aside>`, so what we're doing here is only including that code if the page name is not 'Home'.

(2) In **'CSS'**, find:

```
.page.home {
  margin-right: 16px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

And change it to:

```
.page.home {
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

The `.page` class usually has a margin-left of 260px to provide space for the sidebar, so here we're overriding it when we're on the home page.